# Could not find 'AuthenticationService.init' when Blazor WebAssembly is deployed

Tags: basic-authentication, blazor-webassembly

I created Blazor WebAssembly application with .NET Core backed and with built-in Basic Authentication. No changes in predefined template from Microsoft. I am running application on my development PC without problems. When I deploy application on the hosting server I am receiving following error:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
  Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'AuthenticationService.init' ('AuthenticationService' was undefined).
  Error: Could not find 'AuthenticationService.init' ('AuthenticationService' was undefined).
      at http://tomasoplt-001-site1.dtempurl.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:1287
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at e.findFunction (http://xxx-001-site1.dtempurl.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:1247)
      at b (http://xxx-001-site1.dtempurl.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:2989)
      at http://xxx-001-site1.dtempurl.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3935
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at Object.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (http://tomasoplt-001-site1.dtempurl.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3908)
      at Object.w [as invokeJSFromDotNet] (http://tomasoplt-001-site1.dtempurl.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:64218)
      at _mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor (http://tomasoplt-001-site1.dtempurl.com/_framework/dotnet.5.0.2.js:1:190800)
      at do_icall (http://xxx-001-site1.dtempurl.com/_framework/dotnet.wasm:wasm-function[10596]:0x194e58)
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Also running in the same issue. Running on local machine. 
`Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'AuthenticationService.init' ('AuthenticationService' was undefined).
      Error: Could not find 'AuthenticationService.init' ('AuthenticationService' was undefined).
          at https://localhost:44358/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:1287`

Device time is correct

Answer (score -2):

Problem is your local device time. You have probably out of sync time.